# Parsing Json response to a different Java object each time

Tags: java, json, parsing, jersey

I am using Jersey as a client to parse JSON into Java objects,
The problem is that I am using a service that returns different types of responses that should be mapped to a different Java object each time, so I need a way to step into the parsing process and make an arbitrary decision to tell Jersey what is the exact type of object to parse each time.

EDIT:

For example if I have Java Classes A, B, and C and the Json Response as follows:

```
Data{ 
   -list {
      -0 :{Result should be mapped to A}
      -1 :{Result should be mapped to B}
      -2 :{Result should be mapped to C}
    }
}
```

and the `list` is ArrayList (or can be ArrayList of a super class for the three classes). Now when I ask Jersey to parse this JSON response, It will find an ArrayList when handling `list` and dosen't know what's the exact type of the object to parse into, so it convert the data inside -0, -1, -2 to a linkedHashMap as a key/value pairs.

Comment: have you tried with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) ?

Comment: Side note - Jersey is a JAX-RS provider, not a JSON parsing library. On topic - do the objects being returned have anything in common? Add relevant portions of your code to the question.

Comment: I've added more clarifications up there

Comment: In your schema you can make the list to be a choice of type A, B and C. If all types have the same base type then you can make it a list of that base type. The rest should be handled by the unmarshaller

Answer (score 1):

I use jackson in a jersey client to map json to a hashMap but the mapper will work for pojo's as well.  Hope the following helps.

Get the list elements into an array/list.
Loop through and determine the correct class for each element.
Pass each list element and its respective class name to a method that handles the mapping and returns an object.

```
    import ...
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    public class RequestProcessor {
        void jerseyClient(){

            //rest request
            WebResource resource = ...
            ClientResponse responseContent =   resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class); 

            List list = parseJSonResponse(responseContent);
            for (String jsonListElement : list){
                //determine correct class for jsonListElement

                //Pass jsonListElement and class name to mapper method
                Object obj = mapElementToObject(jsonListElement , className);

                //do something with obj
            }

        }

        private Object mapElementToObject(String jsonString, String className){
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Object obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Class.forName(className);
            return obj;
        }

        private List parseJsonResponse(responseContent){
            //use regexp to replace unnecessary content in response so you have a string
            //that looks like -0:{element values}-1:{element values}-2:{element values}

            //then split the string on "-.*\\:" into a array/list

            //return the list
        }

    }
```